# Adding values of redux-form field array

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

For each new item in a FieldArray I'm looking to add together the contents of a Field inside of the FieldArray called total.

So something like this data structure wise in the form state.

```
test.0.total + test.1.total + test.2.total = testTotal
```

I'm not sure what my options are for accessing the data in the form. formValueSelector works great if I specifically list out the expected fields, but considering this is a FieldArray I won't know how many items there will be at any given time. How would I loop the array structure to add these fields?

I'm currently using a selector that looks like this to return the array.

```
const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm');
      export const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
        const Total = selector(state, 'test');
        return { Total };
      }
```

How could I potentially build a looping mechanism  within the selector?

Something like this works..., but isn't dynamic.

```
    const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm');
      export const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
        const test1 = selector(state, 'test.0.total');
        const test2 = selector(state, 'test.1.total');
        const test3 = selector(state, 'test.2.total');
       return { test1, test2, test3, 
        total: test1 + test2 + test3 };
      }
```

Adding something like this....

```
const test = selector(state, "test");
const sum = test.reduce((total, item) => total + Number(item.total), 0);
```

or even this in the return

```
sum: test.reduce((total, item) => total + Number(item.total), 0);
```

yeilds a TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined... Even though I can see

I can see that the array isn't undefined in the state... Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const sum = arr.reduce((total, item) => total + Number(item.total), 0);
```

`arr.reduce` is what you are looking for.

If you data structure does not contain an object with `item.total` then replace that part with `item`.

Comment: Any thoughts on how this would integrate with redux-form?

Comment: Added the use case. I tried to keep it minimal to prevent TLDR.

Comment: you need to grab your array from state and reduce it just like I did in my example and return the value.

Comment: So this looks like it would work, but returns a TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined. Is there something I'm missing on this?

Comment: is the data structure your passing an array and is it empty? Add this logic before you reduce `arr && arr.reduce'rest of code....'`

Comment: Sorry you can't see out that far in the image, but both total are set to "10"

Comment: so test.0.total = "10"